# Unable to bulk load data into Neptune

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I'm using `awscurl` to bulk load data from s3 into neptune:

I've done the following:

- Ensure the ARN has s3 full access
- Uploaded gremlin csv sample data to existing bucket

The error I get is:

> Couldn't find the aws credential for iam_role_arn: arn:aws:iam::1111111:role/NeptuneAdmin

What is the best way to ensure I have this credential? I'm executing this from local.

### Sample Query

```
awscurl -X POST \                                                          ─╯
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    https://endpoint.us-west-2.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182/loader  -d '
    {
      "source" : "s3://tf-bulk-load-test/vertex.txt",
      "format" : "csv",
      "iamRoleArn" : "arn:aws:iam::1111111111:role/NeptuneAdmin",
      "region" : "us-west-2",
      "failOnError" : "FALSE",
      "parallelism" : "MEDIUM",
      "updateSingleCardinalityProperties" : "FALSE",
      "queueRequest" : "TRUE",
      "dependencies" : []
    }' \
    --header 'host: endpoint.us-west-2.neptune.amazonaws.com' \
    --service neptune-db
```

Comment: Have you added the role to Neptune using the web console or CLI?

Comment: Right as you typed that I noticed there was only a default role applied. Testing it now @KelvinLawrence

Comment: @KelvinLawrence What is the best way to get the credentials to be able to run this? Currently I have to log into a bastion to get the session token, etc. then export locally. Is there a better way?

Comment: Is this so you can use SigV4 with AWS Curl for an IAM enabled cluster?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Your suggestion on attaching the IAM role worked by the way! Just confused on the easiest way to ensure I have credentials set locally for the sigv4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding this as an answer in case others find your question.

The Role that gives Neptune access to S3 needs to be added to Neptune either using the web console or via the CLI. Then when the curl command is issued Neptune will find the Role.

Comment: Thanks Kelvin. This fixed my issue. I'm still confused on how I should grab creds for sigv4 local signing, but maybe I should put in a separate question?

Comment: If you have the AWS CLI installed locally and that user has access to Neptune, one option is to use `aws sts get-session-token`